# Combine properties in serverless.yml

Tags: serverless-framework

I have a `custom` section in `serverless.common.yml`, which is common to all the services. Some services use some additional properties in their `serverless.yml` appart from the defined in the file mentioned before.

My idea would be to perform something like:

```
custom:
  - ${file(../serverless.common.yml):custom}
  - myServiceCustomProperty: 1
```

But this does not work. Any idea about how can I achieve that behaviour?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- ${file(../serverless.common.yml):custom}` is going to dump the array from common so that wont merge. With this approach you need to add each property from the common/custom section individually:

```
custom:
  - foo: ${file(../serverless.common.yml):custom.foo}
  - myServiceCustomProperty: 1
```

or

```
custom: ${file(../serverless.common.yml):custom}
```

Alternatively if your setup is complex you can write a `serverless.js` file instead which allows JS processing. I personally use that to programically merge a dozen yml file - for example when I run `sls offline` I want to add/remove a bunch of stuff so that's a pretty powerful approach.